# THREE.js render in a canvas on top/overlapping another renderer

Tags: canvas, three.js

If I remove the base screen renderer, the canvas one shows, if not, then nothing shows, this seems to only be an issue those when I am trying to render gltf models, if I construct the geometry with THREE.js types, one can render on top of another.

I render my base scene with

```
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: cn } );
        renderer.setSize(cn.width, cn.height);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x111517);
...
 var le = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
     le.load('/users/they/Documents/amit/bird.glb',
      function (gltf) {
      const cube = gltf.scene;
      cube.position.z = -3;
      cube.position.y = 0;
      cube.position.x = 0;
      cube.scale.z = 5;
      cube.scale.y = 5.1;
      cube.scale.x = 5.1;
      cube.rotation.z = 0;
      cube.rotation.y = 0;
      cube.rotation.x = 0;
      scene.add(cube);
});

...
renderer.render(scene,camera2);
```

and my canvas with

```
var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: cn } );
        renderer2.setSize(cn.width, cn.height);
        renderer2.setClearColor(0x111517);
...
renderer2.render(buff_scene,camera);
```

Any help appreciated.